# Method return statement vs try-catch

Tags: java, methods, return, try-catch

As far as I know in Java errors can be reported in two ways: return values and exceptions.

For example, code below:

```java
int methodName(int i, int j) {
    int result;
    
    try {
        result =  i / j; 
        return result;
        // in the case of j = 0, ArtithmeticException() will be thrown
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Some message");
    }
    
    //return result;
}
```

In the case of `j = 0`, an exception will be thrown and caught (by the catch), and "Some message" will be printed.

The question is: If I do not want to return any result from this method in the case of a divide by zero, MUST I return some value or there is another way? I.e. using a 'throw' in the catch clause?

And another observation: if I uncomment the last **'return result'** statement I get the error message:

> variable result might not have been initialized

And if I comment last **'return result'** I get the error message:

> missing return statement

But I've already included the return statement in the try clause.

Thanks!

Comment: it is because of the return type, in your case return type is int. if it is void you dont need to return anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In case of j = 0 exception will be thrown and caught (by catch). And message will be printed. The question is: If I do not want to return any result from this method in the case of dividing by zero I still MUST return some value or there is another way? Using 'throw' from catch clause?

You must either return a value matching the signature (`int` in this example) or `throw` something, otherwise the program will not compile.

> And another observation: if I uncomment last `return result` statement I got an error message: 
>   variable result might not have been initialized

The `result` variable is assigned in a `try` block.
The compiler doesn't know at which exact point the exception might occur.
If an exception occurs before the assignment is completed,
then at the point of the `return result` statement,
the variable `result` might not have a value.
The solution is to set a value before the `try` block.

> And if I comment last 'return result' I got an error message:
>   missing return statement
>   But I've already included return statement in try clause.

In this example, if an exception occurs in the `try` block,
then the `catch` block and the rest of the body of the function is executed,
and there is no other `return` statement to match the signature of the method.
You must return an `int` value on all execution paths.

Comment: @RickSanch3z I reworded that sentence to make it more accurate. You must either throw an exception or return an `int`. There's no other way. Simple as that.

Comment: _italic_You must either return a value matching the signature (int in this example) or throw something, otherwise the program will not compile._italic_ so even if I do not return some `int` I can throw something? Yep. Throwing from 'catch' clause partially solved the problem of not returning some value if I get corrupted result. But I still need to initialize `result` variable.

Comment: @RickSanch3z If you throw in the `catch` block, without using the `result` variable, then you don't need to initialize `result`.

Comment: Thanks. I've checked and it work flawlessly. So in the cases like this I need to throw to the calling function. This compiler scare me. He checks every little aspect. More like an AI.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve can be achieved  by below sample code

> As ArithmeticException is RuntimeException and in case of j=0 exception will be propagated to caller function.

```
int methodName(int i, int j) {
                    return i/j;
               }
```

Comment: Just for the sake of understanding how try-catch work. Thanks.

Comment: refer to java doc for that https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
  static int methodName(int i, int j) {
    if (j == 0) throw new ArithmeticException();
    return i/j;
  }
```

You could also use Integer type for result and initialize it to null and your code would compile:

```
Integer result = null;
```

Either way, the calling code will need to handle the exception or the possible null value.

Comment: This one should work too, because there is no 'try-catch' clause and throwing some exception go straight up to the calling routine.

Comment: And using the 'Integer' object reference probably will work too. When I return 'null' I get <i>NullPointerException</i> that could be caught by calling routine.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you are probably observing is the `scope` of the variable.

When one wants to call a `void` method so that its `return`ing *nothing*; yet, still have it changing the values of a variable, one can put the variable they want changed in the global scope.

An example of how this looks is demo below:

```
public class MyClassName{
    //global scope int
    public static int result;
    //main method
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Let's see what we start at
        System.out.println("By default im at: " + result);
        //Attempt to set global variable as the result of a 0 division
        methodName(1,0);
        System.out.println("I tried to divide by zero but I'm still at: "+result);
        //Attempt to perform normal calculation 25/5
        methodName(25, 5);
        System.out.println("25 divided by 5 is: "+result);
    }
    //method that changes global variable - void means it returns nothing
    public static void methodName(int i, int j) {
            try {
                //try 1 / 0
                result =  i / j; 
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("CATCH:I failed to divide by zero.");
            }
        }
}
```

Output:

```
By default im at: 0
CATCH:I failed to divide by zero.
I tried to divide by zero but I'm still at: 0
25 divided by 5 is: 5
```

Please note the positioning of the global variable, outside the main method.
In this example, the value of the variable `result` is still changed, but is not necessarily `return`ed.